# HTML5 localStorage not persistent in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, local-storage, web-storage

this code works in Firefox and Safari, but in Chrome Version 33.0.1750.149 the localStorage is always empty after restart. (In DevTools as well as accessed through console)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function saveStuff() {
            localStorage.setItem('localKey', 'localValue');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="localStorage">
<button type="button" onclick="saveStuff()">Save</button>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you running from localhost server?

Comment: I tried from localhost as well as deployed on my remote server

Comment: did you get the cookies when browser running? see the link http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") check this to support of localstorage in your browser

Comment: if (typeof(Storage) != "undefined") has no effect - Storage is supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by disabling the option "Block third party cookies".

Comment: So the entire internet needs to change a setting? no.

Answer (score 0):

my same problem solved by disabling the option "Clear cookies and site data when you quit Chrome" in security settings of chrome